# Athena - extract json to rows

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena

I have problem with handle json in AWS Athena

I need to do following transform:

[image]

I've tried to use JSON_extract, but i need to type element number ie. [0] or other number

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please post your json as text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast it to array of rows and use [`UNNEST`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       ('a', JSON '[{"id":1, "category": "test"},{"id":2, "category": "test2"}]')
 ) AS t (xxx, json_string))


SELECT xxx, row.id, row.category
FROM dataset
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(CAST(json_string as ARRAY(ROW (id INTEGER, category VARCHAR)))) as tmp(row)
```

Output:

| xxx | id | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | test |
| a | 2 | test2 |

Comment: @token was glad to help!